# Developing a JDBC Driver

Tags: java, mysql, postgresql, jdbc, cuda

I am trying to research and develop a JDBC driver for an open source database that currently operates from just the command line.  Translating the queries, handling statements and resultsets seems very manageable, however I am very confused when it comes to establishing the connection.

If I build a JDBC driver, does the database need to have a client API for me to do so?  The database is written completely in C++/CUDA, but I want to develop this driver to integrate the database with other visualization tools.  Looking at the MySQL and PostgreSQL JDBC drivers, I cannot seem to discover how the pure connection part is handled and what is required.  Is it necessary to have the database listening on a port and running as a service?  Right now, the database is used by issuing scripts from the command line, and does not currently accept queries on the fly, however that is in development.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: look at the existing drivers harder, there should be a place where a TCP connection is established.

Comment: In principle, it is possible to create a driver which executes command-line scripts, but since there will be a normal network API, count on it.

Comment: Depending on how your DBMS works, looking at code of the [JDBC driver](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc) for SQLite might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in the [Driver](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Driver.html#connect%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Properties%29) API mandating that the URL you pass to DriverManager to connect to your database has a host name and a port. If your database does not listen on the network but is just an executable you run, the url could be the path to that url. For an embedded database your url could carry no information bar the prefix necessary to invoke your driver. So don't worry about network connections if your database doesn't work that way. As comments say, embedded databases like SQLite use non network based URLs.